# Leaving PreferenceActivity, calling Activity still reads old preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I feel I'm missing something obvious, but search took me to several different hits, all of which don't directly access my odd issue.

Have an app with a main activity and a preference activity. Add to that a 'preference' class, which simplifies reading and setting preferences. The main activity has an option menu to get to the preference activity:

Preferences class (included for relevance, same thing happens if I don't use this class to read settings).

```
public class Preferences
{
    public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context)
    {
        SharedPreferences retCont = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return retCont;
    }

    /* Map Page: Show Satellite */
    public static boolean getMapShowSatellite(Context context)
    {
        return Preferences.getPrefs(context).getBoolean(Preferences.getString(context, R.string.option_showSatellite), false);
    }

    public static void setMapShowSatellite(Context context, boolean newValue)
    {
        Editor prefsEditor = Preferences.getPrefs(context).edit();
        prefsEditor.putBoolean(Preferences.getString(context, R.string.option_showSatellite), newValue);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }
}
```

PreferencesActivity:

```
public class AppSettings extends PreferenceActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preferences);

        ListPreference stationType = (ListPreference)this.findPreference(this.getString(R.string.option_filterStationType));
        stationType.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this.stationOrderEnable());
    }
[...]
}
```

The last two lines hook up an event to enable/disable other preferences based on one's selection. That works, as expected.
The simple main activity, and related functions:

```
public class MainMapScreen extends MapActivity
{
    private void launchSettings()
    {
        Intent prefsIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AppSettings.class);
        this.startActivity(prefsIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        Preferences.getMapShowSatellite(); // <-- Returns previous value.
        // Re-start the MyLocation Layer from tracking.
        this._mapView.requestLayout();
    }
[...]
}
```

Okay, so what happens is, let's say we run the app. At app load, the `getMapShowSatellite()` returns `True`. Go into the PreferenceActivity, and change that option to `False`. Exit the PreferenceActivity by hitting the Back button. At this time, the main activity's `onResume()` is called. Getting the `getMapShowSatellite()` at this point returns the previous setting of `True`. Exiting and relaunching the app will then finally return the `False` expected.

I'm not calling `.commit()` manually - and don't think I need to, sicne the setting IS saving, I'm just not getting update values.

What'm I missing? :)
--Fox.

**Edit 2:** Small update. I thought the issue may be the static calls - so temporarily I changed over my Preferences class (above) to be a instantiated class, no more static. I also added the following code to my `onResume()` call in the main activity:

```
//Try reloading preferences?
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String test = sp.getString(Preferences.OPTION_FILTERSTATIONTYPE, "---");
Log.e("BMMaps", test);
```

What is logged at this point, from leaving the PreferenceActivity, is the old setting. Manually reading the preferences file shows me that the .xml file is getting updated with the user's new setting.

Since it's not obvious, I am hooked into Google's Maps API. Because of this, I had to specify two ifferent processes - one for the Main activity (this one) and another for an activity not related to this issue. All other activities, including the PreferencesActivity have no specified `android:process=""` in their definition.

**Edit 3:**
As requested, here's the data preferences file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.filterStationType">V-?</string>
    <boolean name="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.deviceHasLocation" value="false" />
</map>
```

And here is the Preference storage XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Map Options">
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.mapShowSatellite" android:order="1" android:summary="Whether or not to show satellite imagery on the map." android:summaryOff="Standard road map will be shown." android:summaryOn="Satellite imagery will be show." android:title="Show Satellite Layer?" />
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.mapShowScale" android:order="2" android:summary="Whether or not to show the distance bar on the map." android:summaryOff="The distance bar will not be shown on the map." android:summaryOn="The distance bar will be shown on the map." android:title="Show Map Scale?" />
        <CheckBoxPreference android:defaultValue="false" android:key="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.useMetric" android:order="3" android:summary="Whether to use Metric os SI values." android:summaryOff="SI units (mi/ft) will be shown." android:summaryOn="Metric units (km/m) will be shown." android:title="Use Metric?" />
        <ListPreference android:dialogTitle="Station Load Delay" android:entries="@array/static_listDelayDisplay" android:entryValues="@array/static_listDelayValues" android:key="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.mapBMDelay" android:negativeButtonText="Cancel" android:order="4" android:positiveButtonText="Save" android:summary="The delay after map panning before staions are loaded." android:title="Delay Before Loading" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Control Station Filter">
        <ListPreference android:dialogTitle="Station Type" android:entries="@array/static_listStationTypeDisplay" android:entryValues="@array/static_listStationTypeValues" android:key="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.filterStationType" android:negativeButtonText="Cancel" android:positiveButtonText="Save" android:summary="The station type to filter on." android:title="Station Type" android:order="1" />
        <ListPreference android:dialogTitle="Select Station Order" android:entries="@array/static_listStationHOrderDisplay" android:entryValues="@array/static_listStationHOrderValues" android:key="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.filterStationOrder" android:negativeButtonText="Cancel" android:positiveButtonText="Save" android:summary="Station Order to filter by." android:title="Station Order" android:order="2" />
        <ListPreference android:dialogTitle="Select Station Stability" android:entries="@array/static_listStationStabilityDisplay" android:entryValues="@array/static_listStationStabilityValues" android:key="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.filterStationStability" android:negativeButtonText="Cancel" android:positiveButtonText="Save" android:summary="Station stability to filter by." android:title="Station Stability" android:order="3" />
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.filterNonPub" android:summaryOff="Non-Publishable stations will not be shown." android:defaultValue="false" android:summaryOn="Non-Publishable stations will be shown on the map." android:order="4" android:title="Show Non-Publishable" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
    <Preference android:key="temp" android:title="Test" android:summary="Test Item">
        <intent android:targetClass="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps.activities.MainMapScreen" android:targetPackage="com.tsqmadness.bmmaps" />
    </Preference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

When changing the `filterStationType` parameter, and hitting the back button out of PreferenceActivity changes the preferences file from the above from `V-?` to `H-?`, as it should. However, reading the value from the SharedPreferences on the main activity still gives the `V-?`, until app restart. Ah, also, I have a `OnPreferenceChangeListnener()` in the PreferenceActivity, and that is called when the value changes.

**Final Edit**: Apparently, it's the use of named android:process for the given activity. This is needed for Google maps API to allow two separate MapActivitys in the same app use different settings. If the PreferenceActivity is moved to the same named-process, then the code above, reading the setting in the `onResume()` returns the correct value.

Comment: Still looking into your code, but here is a tip for better code: Use `static final String`s instead of string resources for your settings key. These values don't need to be localized and really should never change. These and some small performance reasons make them good candidates for constants.

Comment: What kind of behavior do you see when you put a `OnPreferenceChangeListener` on your `showSatellite` preference?

Comment: @Austyn - Thanks! I'm new to Java, so I'm sure my code is - technically - horrible. :)

Comment: I will look at attaching a listener, and get back tomorrow with an update..

Comment: Another tip, rather than use the static methods of the Preferences class and pass your context every time, why not just keep a reference to a PreferenceManager if you're going to be doing more than a few calls to the static Preference methods?

Comment: @DavidCowden - Thanks for the pointers, I found what's *causing* it, but not sure of a workaround at the moment. See my last edit above.

Comment: After reading through your code I figured it had to be something external to the code samples you gave us. Glad you found the problem.

Comment: Thanks, your "Final Edit" solved my problem (removing android:process).

Answer (score 0):

Since everything checks out, my guess is that you have a typo, or incorrect or undefined, key in your PreferenceActivity's `app_preferences.xml` file for the key `R.string.option_showSatellite` (whatever that string is).  This would result in two keys with [unbeknownst to you] different names that you think point to the same value.  Really, the prefs activity is using one key and your Preference class is using the other -- resulting in two different keys and two different values.

Double check your keys.  Make sure you are not also using the literal `"R.string.options_showSatellite"` as the key in the xml file, but rather, the actual string.  If you want to use the localized version then `@string/options_showSatellite` would work for the key.  However, keys need not be localized.

If you're curious, this can be double checked by opening the preference file that is created by the preference manager in your app's data directory in a standard text editor.

Comment: All of the above check out, oddly. I verified the preferences file is getting updated when the activity ends, thanks!

Comment: @Coyttl Can you post your preferences file?

Comment: Done, posted both the PreferencesLayout and the storage preferences file, above.

Comment: @Coyttl I'm sorry I don't have time to import your code and test it etc.  But all I have left is to tell you to scrap your Preferences class altogether.  Create a member variable to hold a reference to you SharedPreferences for your context.  Obtain that reference in onCreate.  Use that reference whenever you need to get preferences.  Only have your preferences edited in your PreferenceActivity.  Remove your callback if you can -- those can get screwy.  See if you can get it to work simply first.  Then, if you can do that, build your Preference class if you desire.

Comment: @Coyttl Oh, and what is the value of: `R.string.option_filterStationType`?

Answer (score -1):

onResume you have to get a fresh reference to SharedPreferences, otherwise you're just using an object that is already in memory (and has your old values)

EDIT:
Rather than down-voting answers that you don't understand, why not ask for clarification instead?
What I mean is that you should pull your Prefs the correct way (rather than how you're doing it)...

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(), MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And then see what happens.

Comment: Does not change anything, I tried doing a `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` before getting the setting, and it does not change the answer I get back.

Comment: Being new to Java and not knowing what you're doing isn't the best reason to down-vote the (correct) answers of people trying to help you.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I think you have a typo.  You meant "(incorrect) answers of people trying to help you" right? (;

Comment: @David, are you suggesting that there's something incorrect in the way I'm recommending that the OP retrieve his shared prefs?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel The OP's code is correct, albeit odd and not quite Android idiomatic.  But, in either case, you need not "get a fresh reference to SharedPreferences".

Comment: If his variable is displaying the same value as before his commit but then automagically picks up the new value upon reload, then what else can it be? And of course even if your answer above is correct (and it might be) then pulling the Prefs as I describe would solve it, since there would not be any ambiguity as to what file is being pulled.  So... again... where is my answer "wrong"?  Welcome to stack, btw.

Comment: @Dredel - I did not downvote anything. Please don't assume.
Also, getting a a 'new reference to SharedPreferences', like I stated, does not work. The app has to be completely exited and relaunched before the 'new' value is properly read. :(

Comment: Also, technically, on your code, my Preferences class, with all the static calls (as above) **gets a new instance of the SharedPreferences** every time I read a value. (See the `Preferences.getPrefs()` inside the `getMapShowSatellite()` function.

Comment: Look, you can argue with me (pointless) or you can just try what I'm recommending. I promise you it works. If you ONLY grab your SP in the way I describe above, then the instant there's a commit, the next pull of that file will reflect the changes you made. I've been using this technique for two years and have never had a problem, so, I can guarantee that it works as documented. I can't be sure why what you're doing *isn't working, but I can guarantee that what I'm recommending *does work, and if it's not working for you then you're doing something incorrectly(though I don't know what that is)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel - Maybe you missed my comment and code - I tested it, and it till didn't work. Even getting the value like so, by creating a new SharedPrefgerences (sp) and reading the value (bypassing my custom preference class) - still get the old value that way. :(

Comment: I didn't miss your comment, but I guarantee you that  you're doing something wrong. There must be a race condition or something. Let me understand correctly. The problem is exhibited when a user changes the value but clicks the back button rather than moving "forward" to the previous screen?  And you're sure that you're calling the SP in that previous screen onResume? (cause the onCreate ISN'T going to fire on that circumstance). Is this what you're doing?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I guess you don't really get how SharedPreferences work..  The reference you hold to them is always a reference to the most up-to-date object.  It's kinda the whole point of the SharedPreferences.Editor class.  Anyway, I was just trying to let you know [in a friendly manner] that the OP had already tried your solution and it did not work.  Also, as mentioned, neither of us down voted your answer so there must be others that disagree with you.. welcome to stack, btw. (=

Comment: @DavidCowden. I'm totally lost... I was offering the prescribed (by Google) solution to how to correctly use SP and you're telling me that this proves that I don't *really know how SP works? I asure you I do. I was trying to help trouble shoot a bizarre problem and suggesting that it *may lie in the somewhat unorthodox manner in which the OP was implementing SP.  As to my welcoming you, that was done entirely without any sarcasm based on the fact that you appear to be a new user.  I've been here for about 4 years, but I appreciate the counter welcome :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Yeah, right. Anyway, the prescribed-by-Google method is here: [Android Data Storage Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).  It is not what you recommended.  Look, apparently it's a sore subject with you to point out when you may not be entirely correct about something.  I have not been answering questions here as long as you -- I honestly thought a playful comment defending the OP would be harmless.  Sorry.

Comment: @DavidCowden, I  think you may be misreading my comments. Aside from initially (wrongfully) assuming you had down-voted my answer, I didn't think I was sounding sore or aggrieved (and feel neither).  I am almost never correct about anything, so, it would be wildly masochistic for me to also not be able to take that reality in stride.  In this case however, somehow I must have not been clear since that documentation is PRECISELY what I was suggesting! :)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Well, now that there's no hard feelings.  Let me try to explain.  Your method of using `SharedPreferences` suggests the OP obtain a new reference to the `SharedPreference`s in his `onResume` method.  This only need happen in the `onCreate` method.  This is because a `SharedPreference` is simply a "pointer" to the preferences file used by the Activity.  This file is shared across activities in the same application and no information is ever stored in the `SharedPreference` object itself. You *DO*, however, need to reload any preference fields your activity may have loaded `onResume`.

Comment: Or, more ideally, only when it can be verified that the preference values have changed.  So, when returning from say a PreferenceActivity that has altered some preference values, you need only reload the new values if you keep them locally in your activity.  The SP its self does not need to be reloaded.  This is why it is customary to create a MyPrefs class or something for you Application which stores all your preferences locally and updates them in memory whenever they are changed.  OR, retrieves fresh values upon instantiation in which case you *would* need to create a new one `onResume`.

Comment: Genia is right, seen in the Android-docu. If sth. comes up over your activity and will be closed, so your activity is viewable again, onResume() is the one to check out. I've the same problem here, and it doesn't work for me in onResume either, but that must be some Android stuff. The way Genia answered is correct, even I know I have to look elsewhere to fix this weired thing. It's the fault of Android, like loosing checkmarks in scrolling pages etc. It's funny how stupid google-developers are in 2014. Later they can say: "Our Android's now much better than before